# Kamailio SIP Server Connection to Radius Server?

Tags: ubuntu, sip-server, freeradius, kamailio

Hi i'm on a project that which we need to connect our kamailio SIP server 4.1 (installed on ubuntu and i can give SIP service from it i tried with jitsi also install radius tool for Kamailio)  as a client(for AAA i guess) to Radius Server(Windows PC) i've searched on net but didn't find any solution or example can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well i guess  i had to answer my own question thx for nothing :) first of all we need to install two library named by freeradius  and radiusclient-ng then we must configure our radius settings we must set up a shared 'secret' key  for communicate with radius and define radius server ip in file named 'server'  which under directory :/usr/local/etc/radiusclient-ng then create a digest file which points true data's on radius server for example if we consider a authentication process there must be a file named 'digest' and it's content must like this:

```
User-Name = "test", Digest-Response = "631d6d73147add2f9e437f59bbc3aeb7", 
Digest-Realm = "testrealm", Digest-Nonce = "1234abcd" , 
Digest-Method = "INVITE", Digest-URI = "sip:5555551212@example.com", 
Digest-Algorithm = "MD5", Digest-User-Name = "test"
```

//////

```
radclient -f digest localhost auth <shared_secret>
```

and you should be seeing response like this:

```
Received response ID 224, code 2, length = 45
        Reply-Message = "Hello, test with digest"
```